# Disable element in php if/else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce

What i am trying to do is disable/hide the button if this condition is satisfied 
Below is the code for woocommerce website.

**PHP**

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];

    if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
        //*DISABLE BUTTON*//

    }}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="TEST">...</button>
```

Comment: if you want to hide it, you can use CSS - i.e.: `.TEST { display: none; }` - if you want to disable, use a ternary operator with `disabled` and it's serverside.

Comment: use javascript to disable it

Comment: Only when this condition is satisfied? I dont know how to do it , Thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$btn='<button class="TEST" '.(get_the_ID() == $_product->id ? "disabled" : "").">...</button>";
echo $btn;
```

Comment: you read [my comment(?)...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624521/disable-element-in-php-if-else#comment56994836_34624521) I mean my *mind* ;-) yeah, serverside's the way to go with this. JS can always be disabled by a user.

Comment: ternary is always favorite to me :P @Fred-ii-

Comment: same here. Nested ternaries are pretty wild too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add disabled to the button

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];

    if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
        echo '<button class="TEST" disabled>...</button>';
    }else{
        echo '<button class="TEST">...</button>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add `echo` before the two <buttons> to make it more clear.

Comment: @Sheerforce Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$_product->id` to `$_product['id']` may help depending on object/array you have there.

Answer (score 0):

MVC should be used in your project, don't mix php with html code.
U can hide html element by adding style "display: none"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**PHP**

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
   $_product = $values['data'];

   $disable = false;
   if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
       //*DISABLE BUTTON*//
       $disable = true
   }}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="TEST" <?php echo $disable? 'disabled' : '' ?>>...</button>
```